# Moderncv package provides error for optional arguments: why?

Tags: errors, moderncv, vertical-spacing, arguments

So I'm writing my CV using `moderncv` from TeXLive on Arch Linux. Note that I am on Emacs, where an expanding snippet for `cventry` gives me this suggestion: `\cventry{year}{job}{employer}{city}{description}`. Note that the grade argument is missing, however this **should** not be a problem, since [the documentation](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/manual/moderncv_userguide.pdf) says:

```latex
\cventry{years}{degree/job title}{institution/employer}
{localization}{optional: grade/...}
{optional: comment/job description}
```

"where the last three arguments are optional" (I don't know why in the example only the last two are marked as optional, but that's a minor thing).

Now, I have this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{moderncv}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\recomputelengths{}

\firstname{Alessandro}
\familyname{Bertulli}
\address{via @@@@@@@ @@}{@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@}
\mobile{@@@@@@@@@@}
\email{@@@@@@@.@@@@@@@@@@@.com}

\nopagenumbers{}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\begin{document}
%\makecvtitle{}
\section{Educazione}
\label{sec:educazione}
\cventry{2015}{Scuola superiore}{L.S.S. ``Elio Vittorini''}{Milano}{voto: @@}
\cventry{2019}{Laurea Triennale in Ingengeria Informatica}{Politecnico di Milano}{}{voto: @@}
\closesection{}
% \cvlanguage{English}{Advanced}{B2 Cambridge level}
\end{document}
```

Note that the number of arguments is lower than as specified on the manual. Compiling it, I get errors similar to:

```
BAD BOX: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 17--17

--- TeX said ---

--- HELP ---
Check your output for extra vertical space.  If you find some, it was
probably caused by a problem with a \\ or \newline command---for
example, two \\ commands in succession. This warning can also be
caused by using the sloppypar environment or \sloppy declaration, or
by inserting a \linebreak command.
```

The errors go away if I put the correct number of arguments.

- Is this an error of my LaTeX distribution?
- Are the number of arguments actually required, and the word "optional" simply means they can be left empty (`{}`) but present? (If yes, I'll issue a bug request to the Emacs package providing that snippet)

Comment: I just looked at the definition of `\cvline` in `moderncv.cls` and it takes 6 mandatory arguments (plus one optional one for spacing but for that you would use `[...]` at the start of the command). In addition to the emacs package, you might also consider a report at the [github page for moderncv](https://github.com/moderncv), since its documentation is very misleading.

Comment: I accidentally wrote `\cvline` instead of `\cventry` in my previous comment, but it's too late to edit it. Hope it was clear what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classically, LaTeX commands can have two types of arguments:

- **Mandatory** arguments that are given within curly braces and that *must* be present and
- **optional** arguments that can be given within square brackets and that may be omitted completely.

TeX syntax would allow us to define commands whose arguments behave differently (and some LaTeX packages do). But broadly speaking this is the distinction.

If commands are defined with LaTeX's classical `\newcommand` interface, only the first argument can be optional, all other arguments are mandatory.

The newer `\DeclareDocumentCommand` and friends allow for a freer syntax choice. But even there regular optional arguments are given in square brackets and regular mandatory arguments in curly braces.

Commands with mandatory arguments are typically implemented in a way that forces TeX to "look" for the mandatory argument if it is not given. That means that if a mandatory argument is missing, TeX might just hoover up the next few things following the command and may pretend that these were the missing arguments. This can have unintended consequences.

---

Initially, [`moderncv.cls` (ll. 510-512)](https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv/blob/f7971f8c946e612808897d885a9a0d3729fee4d9/moderncv.cls#L510-L512) defines `\cventry` as a dummy command

```
% makes a typical resume job / education entry
% usage: \cventry[spacing]{years}{degree/job title}{institution/employer}{localization}{optionnal: grade/...}{optional: comment/job description}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{}
```

It is then redefined depending on the selected style. Those redefinitions differ, but they are structurally similar. [`moderncvbodyi.sty`, ll. 110-118](https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv/blob/f7971f8c946e612808897d885a9a0d3729fee4d9/moderncvbodyi.sty#L110-L118), to pick one example, has

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    \strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

Syntactically, this clearly defines a command with one optional argument (the first, to be given in square brackets if desired) and six mandatory arguments (to be given in curly braces). There is some code to deal with the cases where some of the mandatory arguments are empty.

This means that `\cventry` must always be supplied with six arguments, which usually means you need six pairs of curly braces. The last three of those six may be left empty, but the braces may not be omitted - if they are TeX tries to gobble up the following stuff as arguments, which may result in occasionally very weird errors.

So ``` \cventry{2015}{Scuola superiore}{L.S.S. ``Elio Vittorini''}{Milano}{voto: @@} ``` is not OK, it has to be

```
\cventry{2015}{Scuola superiore}{L.S.S. ``Elio Vittorini''}{Milano}{voto: @@}{}
```

---

The wording in the documentation is extremely unfortunate, if not outright misleading, since classically an optional argument is one that is given in square brackets and that can be omitted entirely and not one that is given in curly  braces and that can be left empty.

If you want, you can raise this issue at https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv/issues to ensure that the documentation is more accurate. You may also want to raise the issue with the Emacs package that provided the snippet as the arguments need to be given.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the definition of the command

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
    \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
        {\bfseries#3}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
        \strut%
        \ifx&#7&%
        \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

you will see that it expects to find 7 parameters, with only one, the first, optional (and default value .25em) and tests for empty in #4, #5 and #6.

In the code you will find

```
% makes a typical resume job / education entry
% usage: \cventry[spacing]{years}{degree/job title}{institution/employer}{localization}{optionnal: grade/...}{optional: comment/job description}
```

So "optional" means `{}` here.